# How to open immediate popups in UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, javascript-injection

I've seen HTML re-writing examples that allow opening pop-ups that are triggered by clicking on a link, but what if the pop-up is not triggered by a link and just gets launched when the page loads (like popuptest.com/popuptest9.html)?

I've put the following in shouldStartLoadWithRequest, and can now display an alert every time window.open is called.. But how do I pick off the URL being passed to window.open?

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.open = function (open) { alert(window.location) } (window.open);"];
```

Need a javascript pro here...

Comment: Did you try implementing the shouldStartLoadWithRequest? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

Comment: You can get the URL from the request argument in that delegate method, no JS injection needed.

Comment: updated issue.. putting it in shouldStartLoadWithRequest works! the only problem now is how do i get the url that is passed to window.open?

Comment: @Swanson Did you find the solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish running a task on page load with a bit of JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(
    function ()
    {
       alert("I'm Ready!"); 
    });
```

This script will execute once the DOM has been constructed. You can read more about this [here](https://api.jquery.com/ready/). Alternatively you can use `.load()` which will fire when content has been rendered however, as the documentation shows the `.ready()` is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery (or whatever scripting language) code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the URL from the request argument, like so:

```
request.URL
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType

Comment: i'm not trying to get the url passed to shouldStartLoadWithRequest.. I'm trying to get the url passed to window.open

Comment: Im talking about that one:)